# Snowflake: Turning staged S3 URL into the columns for a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've staged some data from S3 into Snowflake, which I want to COPY into a table. However, I want some of the columns in the table to be values from the URL path of the staged data. For example -

The data is stored like this - s3://bucket1/subbucket1/object_ID/instance/type/file.json

I want to store the data in a table that looks like this:

| object_ID | instance | type | values from file (JSON) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2222 | 3333 | type1 | {JSON} |

The only way I've been able to find that helps filter on a COPY INTO command is the PATTERN function, which allows you to copy over only values specified through a regex. Using that function, I've only been able to pull back certain files, but the resulting table has the single value of the full path.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the `METADATA$FILENAME` function during your `COPY INTO` command?  Have you tried parsing it directly as part of your `SELECT`?

Something along the lines of:

```
COPY INTO ...
SELECT SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME,'/',5),
       SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME,'/',6),
       SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME,'/',7),
       $1
FROM @STAGE;
```

I haven't tried this to see if it works in a COPY command, but it definitely works when selecting directly against the stage, so I'd imagine it'll work for the COPY, as well.  If it doesn't, let me know.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it got close. Here's what happened:

COPY INTO Audience_Tracking
FROM (SELECT 
       TRY_CAST(SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME,'/',4) AS string) as deckPin,
       TRY_CAST(SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME,'/',5) AS int) as instance_id,
       TRY_CAST(SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME,'/',6) AS string) as type,
       TRY_CAST(SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME,'/',7) AS string) as socket,
       $1
      FROM @JSON_TRACKING_DATA
      WHERE type = 'audience');

Resulted in: SQL compilation error: COPY statement only supports simple SELECT from stage statements for import.

Comment: Looks like selecting from a Stage only supports really minimal SELECT statements.

Comment: Any difference if you remove the TRY_CAST?  There are definitely some transformations that don't work, but I wonder if its the TRY_CAST vs. the SPLIT_PART.

Comment: Also, what if you change from COPY INTO to an INSERT INTO?  You'd lose the copy history if you did it this way, though.

Comment: Mike, thank you! the TRY_CAST was not the issue, it still had a difficult time.

Comment: Ok, sorry that didn't work out for you.  Did you try using an INSERT INTO, instead?